# After "keypress" on textarea, unable to fill value using onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have textarea, values entered in textarea should be displayed in a text box. This I have done using the "keypress" event on textarea. This works fine.
Now when I try to fill textarea by clicking the div (some text content), this is not working.

But before the "keypress" event I am able to fill the textarea successfully.

*HTML:*

```
<div id="dvfilltextarea" style="cursor: pointer;">Click here and check</div>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="txtvalue" id="txtDisplayMessage">
<br/>
<textarea id="txtMessage" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#txtMessage").bind("keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#txtDisplayMessage").val($("#txtMessage").val());
        $("#txtMessage").val("");
    }
});

$("#dvfilltextarea").click(function() {
    $("#txtMessage").html("div clicked");
});});
```

Link : http://jsfiddle.net/6VkfD/1/

Not able to understand what is happening here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value of the text area with some text. So use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to do so. [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) doesn't set the value of textarea. It can be applied on div, p etc tags rather input elements.So try this,

```
$("#txtMessage").val("div clicked");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `val` http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
$("#dvfilltextarea").click(function() {
    $("#txtMessage").val("div clicked");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/6VkfD/3/

Answer (score 0):

change the html to val

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

$("#txtMessage").bind("keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#txtDisplayMessage").val($("#txtMessage").val());
        $("#txtMessage").val("");
    }
});

$("#dvfilltextarea").click(function() {
    $("#txtMessage").val("div clicked");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works with all events, tested ;p

```
  function update(){
    $("#txtDisplayMessage").val($("#txtMessage").val());
  };
  $('#txtMessage').keydown(function(e) {
    update();
  }).focusout(function(){
    update();
  }).bind('input propertychange', function() {
    update();
  });
```